# Trigger an action depending on the item selected in the dropdown menu

Tags: python

I'm trying to trigger an action depending on the each item in the dropdown menu but I cannot find the way to do it.

The script will create new buttons and each of them will have a dropdown with 3 options, one selects a cube, another one selects the light and the third one selects the camera. I get no errors in the script, just it won't select the items that I have set as options in the enum.

Here is a screenshot of the script, just posted a stripped down version of the code that still works.[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Operator
from bpy.types import Scene
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty

class SceneItems(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    value : bpy.props.IntProperty()
    
    my_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "Dropdown",
        description= "text",
        items= [('OP1', "Select Cube", "", "MESH_CUBE", 1),
                ('OP2', "Select Light", "", "OUTLINER_OB_LIGHT", 2 ),
                ('OP3', "Select Camera", "", "VIEW_CAMERA", 3)
        ]
    )

class SelectItems(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.select_cube_operator"
    bl_label = "Select Cube Button"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        selcube = context.scene.newbutton
        
        if selcube.context.scene.newbutton == 'OP1':
            bpy.data.objects["Cube"].select_set(True)
                    
        if selcube.context.scene.newbutton == 'OP2':
            bpy.data.objects["Light"].select_set(True)
            
        if selcube.context.scene.newbutton == 'OP3':
            bpy.data.objects["Camera"].select_set(True)           
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class AddButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.add_button_operator"
    bl_label = "Add Button"

    def execute(self, context):
        id = len(context.scene.newbutton)
        new = context.scene.newbutton.add()
        new.name = str(id)
        new.value = id
        return {'FINISHED'}

class RemoveButtonOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.remove_button_operator"
    bl_label = "Remove Button"

    id : bpy.props.IntProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.scene.newbutton.remove(self.id)
        print("Pressed button ", self.id)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class FancyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Fancy Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("scene.add_button_operator")
        
        for idx, item in enumerate(context.scene.newbutton):
                row = self.layout.row(align=True)

                row.prop(item, "my_enum", text="")
                row.operator("scene.remove_button_operator", text='', icon = "PANEL_CLOSE").id = idx

classes = (
    SceneItems,
    AddButtonOperator,
    FancyPanel,
    RemoveButtonOperator,
    SelectItems,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.newbutton = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = SceneItems)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I don't understand your end goal.  Do you have to create the buttons dynamically?  Why can't you just add three items to the panel in the source code, each of which has a layout entry for the enum property?  Do you want the dropdown to appear in the panel, or can it be invoked by pressing the button?

Comment: Yes this is part of a biggish script, I cleaned it up to post it here. I have other that do something for each row. I will update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: That helps, but as far as I can tell, the buttons in the same row as a dropdown is unrelated to the dropdown.  The "Add Button" button adds a new _row_.  The row appears to contains a button, two checkboxes,  the dropdown and remove button.  In your example code, you're not getting any action, because there's nothing in your layout that can invoke the `scene.select_cube` operator, which is the one containing the `execute` routine that does the selection.